# How to use postgresql as key-value store from python?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2, key-value-store

I need to convert from [gdbm](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dbm.html) to [postgresql](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html) for my key/value store.

It appears that I will have to replace

```
import dbm.gnu

def get_value(db, key):
    return json.loads(db[key])

db = dbm.gnu.open(...)
v = get_value(db, "foo")
```

with

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column, Text
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB

db = sqlalchemy.create_engine("...")
engine = db.connect()
meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData(engine)

id_col = Column('id', Text, primary_key=True)
data_col = Column('data', JSONB)
sqlalchemy.Table("my_table", meta, id_col, data_col)

meta.create_all()

# populate the table with 40M "id"-->JSON records
engine.execute(
    my_table.update(),
    id="foo",
    data={"a":3, "b":17, "c":[2,6,0]})

my_table = sqlalchemy.table("my_table", id_col, data_col)

def get_value(db, key):
    res = engine.execute(db.select().where(db.c.id == key)).fetchall()
    assert len(res) == 1
    return res[0][1]

v = get_value(my_table)
```

this looks somewhat scary (especially if I add `echo` and see all the SQL
generated for these simple key-value operations).

Is there a better way?

PS. I could also use [`psycopg`](http://initd.org/psycopg/) instead of [`sqlalchemy`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html) directly, but that would make me write SQL *myself* ;-(

Comment: ORM generated SQL is often somewhere between puzzling and downright scary. If you just use Postgres in pure key/value mode I would rather write the SQL myself. Or just not look at the ORM generated code :)

Comment: do the JSON objects share a common schema?

Comment: You are not using the ORM. Those are so called Core constructs: "The SQLAlchemy Expression Language presents a system of representing relational database structures and expressions using Python constructs. These constructs are modeled to resemble those of the underlying database as closely as possible, while providing a modicum of abstraction of the various implementation differences between database backends." Iow you're in a way already writing SQL yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not use postgresql as a key-value store.

The key-value store (except in rare cases) is structured around a schema based on key composition that layout the data in multidimensional space that may or may not map directly the concepts of SQL tables. Otherwise said, there is a database abstraction that lives in the key-value store.

There is not enough information to say, simply replace the key-value store with a 2 columns table. If you do that you will most likely end up with the worst of both worlds.

Comment: "You must not use postgresql as a key-value store."  Except, postgresql has a  "hstore" data type for storing sets of key/value pairs within a single PostgreSQL value, since at least version 9.1, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/hstore.html for the current documentation

Comment: Like I said, there is not enough information to just say replace "gdbm" with two columns or even hstore.  Can a hstore value handle bigger than memory data?